# collect2: ld returned 1 exit status error

Tags: c++

I have three files like the following:

**Movie.h**

```
struct Movie{
    char title[30];         // the hour of the current time
    char director[30];          // the minute of the current time
    int length;
} ;

void printMovieInfo(Movie *s);
```

**Movie.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>

#include "Movie.h"

using namespace std;

void printMovieInfo(Movie *s){

    cout << "Hi";

}
```

**and a file with the main**

```
#include "Movie.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct Movie *m;
    printMovieInfo(m);
}
```

When I run the program, I get the following error:

```
    collect2 ld returned 1 exit status
```

and warnings:

```
/tmp/ccIe4dlt.o In function `printMovieInfo()':
Movie.cpp (.text+0x0): multiple definition of `printMovieInfo()'
/tmp/cc91xrNB.o HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

I just want to call a function to print "Hi", but I'm not sure why I get this error

Comment: You have to include header file, not `.cpp` file

Comment: And giving the header an include guard is always a good idea as well.

Comment: Include "Movie.h" in main.cpp, not "Movie.cpp". The duplicate symbols means you're already properly building+linking with Movie.cpp, so changing just the `#include` should solve pour problem.

Comment: Also need to compile everything and link it: `g++ -o SayHi FileWithMain.cpp Movie.cpp`

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `#include "movie.cpp"` you want `#include "movie.h"`!

It is extremely rare the correct thing to include a ".cpp" file - they are compiled as separate units, and then linked together by the linker (here called `collect2`).